# Get rid of ?frontend= parameter

Tags: parameter

CMS-Pages like imprint, terms, etc ... seem to have ?frontend=xxxxxxx GET-variable in URL.

How can I stop Magento from adding this to the URL?

Comment: How are the links for those pages generated?

Comment: just hard like <a href="/mypage/"> ... do I need to use {{store_url="mypage"}}?

Comment: if you are in a cms page/block use `<a href="{{store url="mypage"}}">...</a>`. If you are in a template use `<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'mypage'))?>">...</a>`

Answer (score 1):

To turn the option off in Magento 1.4 and later, set "Use SID on Frontend" to "No" under System → Configuration → Web → Session Validation Settings:

[image]

Thereafter, do a **full** cache flush & reindex:

`System` → `Cache Management` → `Select All` → `Refresh` → `Submit`

&

`System` → `Index Management` → `Select All` → `Refresh` → `Submit`

Comment: thx but already done, still got that link

Comment: And you've performed a full cache flush & reindex thereafter? I've updated my answer as well.

Comment: the trick for me was like marius recommended to use {{store url="mypage"}}, but thx anyway!

Comment: No problem. Marius the Magento guru :)